# xpath query to parse html tags

Tags: dom, xpath, html-parsing

I need to parse the following sample html using xpath query..

```
<td id="msgcontents">
 <div class="user-data">Just seeing if I can post a link... please ignore post
  <a href="http://finance.yahoo.com">http://finance.yahoo.com</a>
 </div>
</td>

<td id="msgcontents">
 <div class="user-data">some text2...
  <a href="http://abc.com">http://abc.com</a>
 </div>
</td>

<td id="msgcontents">
 <div class="user-data">some text3...      
 </div>
</td>
```

The above html may repeat n no of times in a page.

Also sometimes the ..... portion may be absent as shown in the above html blocks.

What I need is the xpath syntax so that I can get the parsed strings as

```
 array1[0]= "Just seeing if I can post a link... please ignore post ttp://finance.yahoo.com" 
 array[1]="some text2 htp://abc.com"
 array[2]="sometext3"
```

Comment: (1) You can use the "code" button to indent your HTML code so it renders with angle brackets without mangling it.  (2) Your question is ambiguous because the href attribute has the same value as the anchor text, and you don't clarify which one you are after. (3) HTML is not necessarily valid XML, so understand that using XPATH (which requires XML) may not be the idle route unless you can coax all of your HTML into valid XML.

Comment: The XPath for selecting such `div` elements is `/html/body/table/tr/td/div[@class='user-data']`. Then you need the string value for each node. That depends on DOM method of the host language.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like the following:

```
   $remote = file_get_contents('http://www.sitename.com');
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    //Error suppression unfortunately, as an invalid xhtml document throws up warnings.
    $file = @$dom->loadHTML($remote);

    $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

    //Get all data with the user-data class.
    $userdata = $xpath->query('//*[contains(@class, \'user-data\')]');

    //get links
    $links = $xpath->query('//a/@href');
```

So to access one of these variables, you need to use `nodeValue`:

```
$ret = array();
foreach($userdata as $data) {
  $ret[] = $data->nodeValue;
}
```

**Edit:** I thought I'd mention that this will get *all* the links on a given page, I assume this is what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
concat(/td/div/text[1], ' ', /td/div/a)
```

**You can use instead of the ' ' above, whatever delimiter you'd like** to appear between the two strings.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I tried your solution but did not get my result. I have edited the question. Please review it.